# What are the circumstances when an overwrite happens in a git merge, instead of a conflict?

Tags: git, merge, version-control, rebase

I've noticed at times code being overwritten from merges between our team, and am not 100% sure on the best approach for this not to happen.

An example would be we have `master`, and some branch `a`. I am curious about the differences between merging `a` into `master`, and merging `master` into `a`, and when it overwrites something, vs let's us know there are CONFLICTS.

I am also wondering on what the best approach is, I know we can git stash/apply, but what if the branch already has committed changes. I have looked a bit into rebasing, but everything says rebasing can be dangerous.

Comment: When you merge a branch into another, if both sides modify the same file(s), there will has merge conflicts. So what do you want to do, resolve the conflicts by keeping one side version or use stash, rebase etc to replace git merge?

Answer (score 0):

> I know we can git stash/apply, but what if the branch already has committed changes. I have looked a bit into rebasing, but everything says rebasing can be dangerous.

both stash and rebase uses same merging backend as merging, so if anything happen during merging, can happen during that operations

But, merging preserved the "true" history, so in case of it made wrong you can get back to the merging point and analyse what went wrong. From what I know, merging should not do it by itself. So unless there is a concrete example, little can be said.